# Batch script to rename folders recursively where a path contains a variable string

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that recurses through the folder structure from an anchor position (C:\Temp\Corporate Services). For each folder in the tree, if the path contains the word Registers then I need all subfolders below Registers to be prefixed with (Reg). 
Here is a sample of the tree - there are 400 Companies with the same folder structure as follows:

```
> tree
C:.

└───Temp
    └───Corporate Services
        ├───Company A
        │   ├───Agreements
        │   │   ├───2017
        │   │   └───2018
        │   └───Registers
        │       ├───2016
        │       ├───2017
        │       └───2018
        │           └───Folder1
        │               └───Folder2
        └───Company B
        │   ├───Agreements
        │   │   ├───2017
        │   │   └───2018
        │   └───Registers
        │       ├───2016
        │       ├───2017
        │       └───2018
        │           └───FolderX
        │               └───Folder Y
        └───Company C...
```

So where the full path is C:\Temp\Corporate Services\Registers\2016, the 2016 folder needs to be renamed to (REG)2017. Same for 2017 and 2018. EDIT: The tree can extend beyond the year folders into further subfolders so will need to rename those as well.

I've managed to recurse through the tree but am stuck when analysing the path for the 'registers' string. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
@echo off
set /A o=0
echo o starts as %o%

call :treeProcess
rem goto:eof

:treeProcess
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A i=1
REM echo i is %i%

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /ad /s /b "C:\Temp\Corporate Services"') do (

echo root: %%f


for /D %%d in (*) do (

    cd %%d


    Set str1=%%~f
    Set var=%str1:registers=%
    echo %var%

    REM if not "%var%"==%str1% echo found reg

    set /A o=%i%+1

    if %o%==2 goto :eof 
    if %o%==1 call :treeProcess
    cd ..
    )
ENDLOCAL
        )
:eof
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Updated the tree with thanks to LotPings for superior sample. Also applied updates to the code sample in line with comments from aschipfl. Complete rookie here but learning a whole heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has got several flaws; some of them are:

- you are writing to and reading from variables within the same block of code (`str1`, `var`, `o`), which requires [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html);
- the switch `/R` of `dir` is totally unneeded here (I guess you are not interested in alternate data streams);
- you are attempting to recursively call the sub-routine `:treeProcess` (calling it by itself), which could work in some situations, but not here, because you are already enumerating all (sub-)directories recursively (`dir /S`) anyway; recursive calls are very dangerous, you might easily reach the nesting limit, for instance;
- you should never use `::`-style comments in code blocks as they might lead to unexpected results;
- there is a (commented out) `call :EOF`, which should read `goto :EOF`;
- there is a (commented out) `if` comparison of a quoted string with an unquoted one, so it is never going to be true;

Anyway, since you want to rename directories on a certain hierarchy level only, I recommend not to use recursion in order to avoid unintended changes. Rather I would only process the directories in the dedicated grand-child directories:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\Temp\Corporate Services"
set "_NAME=Registers"
set "_PREF=(REG)"

rem // Enumerate immediate child directories of root directory:
for /D %%A in ("%_ROOT%\*") do (
    rem // Try to change into certain grand-child directory:
    2> nul pushd "%%~A\%_NAME%" && (
        rem // Enumerate grand-grand-child directories and filter them:
        for /F "delims=" %%C in ('
            2^> nul dir /B /A:D "*" ^| findstr /I /V /B /C:"%_PREF%"
        ') do (
            rem // Rename directories that have not yet been:
            ECHO ren "%%~C" "%_PREF%%%~C"
        )
        rem // Return from grand-child directory:
        popd
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

#### Edit

To handle sub-directories of the grand-grand-children too, you could use this code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\Temp\Corporate Services"
set "_NAME=Registers"
set "_PREF=(REG)"

rem // Enumerate immediate child directories of root directory:
for /D %%A in ("%_ROOT%\*") do (
    rem // Try to change into certain grand-child directory:
    2> nul pushd "%%~A\%_NAME%" && (
        rem // Enumerate grand-grand-child directories recursively and filter them:
        for /F "delims=" %%C in ('
            2^> nul dir /S /B /A:D "*" ^| findstr /I /V /R /C:"\\%_PREF%[^\\]*$"
        ') do (
            rem // Rename directories that have not yet been:
            ECHO ren "%%~C" "%_PREF%%%~nxC"
        )
        rem // Return from grand-child directory:
        popd
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: all excellent answers - this one works for the purposes of what needs to be accomplished

Comment: just realised that the directories extend beyond the grand-grand-child level, what switch should be used to traverse all folders in the immediate child directory?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow; could you please provide an example?

Comment: Sure - further updated the tree to show further sub folders that require the _PREF prefix. Basically there are N-folders in the tree which is why I initially went for a recursion. Putting the /S switch into your code didn't work, i.e. the script didn't process the grand-grand-grandchildren. Hope that clarifies the dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

- The SearchDir in the following batch may look wrong,
  but `Dir /B/S/AD` starts with the given path and recursivly searches for the last element - so efficiently returning only matching folders
- which is the starting point for the `for /d` enumerating the folders in there.
- The echo to findstr ensures that folders already having the prefix `(REG)` are not processed again.
- technically being a one liner it could be executed in the cmd line when replacing `%%` with `%`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\15\SO_50868596.cmd
@Echo off
set "SearchDir=C:\Temp\Corporate Services\Registers"

For /f "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S /AD "%SearchDir%"') Do For /D %%B in ("%%A\*"
) Do Echo=%%~nxB|findstr /i "^(REG)" 2>&1>NUL || Ren "%%~fB" "(REG)%%~nxB"
```

Sample tree output:

```
> tree
C:.

└───Temp
    └───Corporate Services
        ├───Company A
        │   ├───Agreements
        │   │   ├───2017
        │   │   └───2018
        │   └───Registers
        │       ├───(REG)201
        │       ├───(REG)201
        │       └───(REG)201
        └───Company B
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  FOR /L %%y IN (2016,1,2018) DO (
   IF "%%~na" == "%%y" FOR %%p IN ("%%~dpa.") DO IF /i "%%~np"=="Registers" ECHO(REN "%%a" "(REG)%%y"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

First, perform a directory-scan and for each directory found, check that the "name" part (`%%~na`) is one of the target years `%%y`.

If it is, then if the name part of the parent directory is "Registers", do the rename.

Oh - BTW - it's not a good idea to use `::-Comments` within a `code block` (Parenthesised sequence of lines) as `::` is a label which can break the block. Use `REM` within `code blocks`.

Oh - just realised you want *all* subdirectories renamed, not just `2016..2018`.

Simpler code:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  FOR %%p IN ("%%~dpa.") DO IF /i "%%~np"=="Registers" ECHO(REN "%%a" "(REG)%%~na"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: For some reason, the code above doesn't step into the all subdirectories. I've updated the questions with a few more subfolders to show what I'm dealing with. Here's what I used for testing: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Temp\Corporate Services\"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  FOR %%p IN ("%%~dpa.") DO IF /i "%%~np"=="Agreements" ECHO(REN "%%a" "(AGMT)%%~na"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF